# Disable virtual numpad on laptop while not affecting bluetooth numpads?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, numlock

my laptop has an annoying feature - it is a soft numpad.. there is no actual numpad.. instead when you turn it on, letters on the keyboard become numpad keys.

Problem is that whenever I turn on numlook via my bluetooth numpad, the keyboard goes into numpad mode making it impossible to type on.

How can I disable such a thing? what is the windows way to do it? or if there isn't one, what 3rd party tool could I use for this?